# What collection of if statements would be more efficient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

Apologies in advance for not 'Racing my horses'

Haven't seen this exact question anywhere but was just curious what type of if statement would be more efficient, or if it is negligible and would just be based of the compiler.

```
if (data[i].Occupied) {
    var color1 = "#E51616";
    var drop1 = "";
    var drag1 = "LocationDrag";
    var work1 = data[i].Works_Order_Number;
} else {
    var color1 = "#008000";
    var drop1 = "tdDrop";
    var drag1 = "";
    var work1 = "";
}
if (data[i + 1].Occupied) {
    var color1 = "#E51616";
    var drop1 = "";
    var drag1 = "LocationDrag";
    var work1 = data[i].Works_Order_Number;
} else {
    var color1 = "#008000";
    var drop1 = "tdDrop";
    var drag1 = "";
    var work1 = "";
}
```

OR

```
var color1 = data[i].Occupied ? "#E51616" : "#008000";
var color2 = data[i + 1].Occupied ? "#E51616" : "#008000";
var drop1 = data[i].Occupied ? "" : "tdDrop";
var drop2 = data[i + 1].Occupied ? "" : "tdDrop";
var drag1 = data[i].Occupied ? "LocationDrag" : "";
var drag2 = data[i].Occupied ? "LocationDrag" : "";
var work1 = data[i].Occupied ? data[i].Works_Order_Number : "";
var work2 = data[i + 1].Occupied ? data[i + 1].Works_Order_Number : "";
```

Comment: Use what is more readable to you and your team.

Comment: Thanks, I know! I'm not really asking for what one is better i'm just curious what would be more efficient code performance wise

Comment: At first glance, the first solution does two comparisons, the second one does 8. Not sure if the compiler will optimize the second solution.

Comment: You should not ask us, [go race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Haha that's a good article I will go race my horses. Thanks

Comment: The answer would depend on hardware , platform and compiler(s). You can't predict the machine code very well from looking at C#, and then there is the depth of your [pipeline](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56388/depth-of-a-pipeline-in-a-cpus-architecture).

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider That's what I was thinking, Thanks!

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks a lot that pipeline question helped!

Comment: Why you don't use a loop?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is already within a loop, admittedly I could use another!

Comment: @MichaelStaples: why do you define the variables in the scopes of the `if`-statements and not outside?

Comment: @TimSchmelter To be honest Tim I haven't been optimising my code, I was just curious on what type of statement would be more efficient

Comment: @MichaelStaples: This has nothing to do with optimisation. What TimSchmelter wants to point out is, that when you defining a variable within an if-clause then this variable will only be available within the scope and not outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not test yourself? Just use the Stopwatch class in the System Diagnostics namespaces and see if you can find any differences in execution time.

However I'm going to be pretty confident in saying you won't find a difference or it will be so small it doesn't matter. So as someone else said, readability wins here.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually know that was possible! Would you have any recommendation on a tutorial of some form demonstrating the stopwatch?

Comment: It's a pretty simple class to use. Here is the Microsoft documentation 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: Oh sorry I misread and thought it was a tool! Thanks